# Node.js require can't find libdpfpdd.so.2 file, which is in the same directory as my .node file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to include a node module that was compiled for nw.js using the `nw-gyp` command (full command: `nw-gyp rebuild --production --runtime=node-webkit --target=0.29.1`)

When I run the require, it throws an error that says "libdpfpdd.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", even though that file exists and is in the same directory as the .node file. Below I leave my code and the full error message
Has anyone experienced somthing similar? Do you know where node is trying to find that file? Any help will be appreciated

```js
path = require('path')
require(path.join(myPath, "FingerprintReader.node"))
```

```
Uncaught Error: libdpfpdd.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:721)
    at Module.load (module.js:586)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:526)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:518)
    at Module.require (module.js:618)
    at require (internal/module.js:11)
    at self.require (<anonymous>:11:26)
    at <anonymous>:2:1
```

Comment: What is the value of `myPath` variable? seems this is what causing  your issue if its not defined.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman I get it using `path.parse(require.resolve('fingerprintReader')).dir`, and it is correct. It seems to be able to find the .node file though, since the error says it cannot find libdpfpdd.so.2